# The sitemap generator doesnt find the second language files, i am using tailwindcss

Tags: html, tailwind-css, multilingual, sitemap, tailwind-3

I have built a website and i have a problem with sitemap generator. It doesn't see the html files in "en" folder where are the second language files. What should i do to make it find them? What am i missing? i have uploaded a photo of my root files and the tailwind.config.js

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `content: ["./**/*.{html,js}]`.

That should still pick up files in the root folder, and html, js files in any subfolders.